# Can't install react-native-cli after following tutorial

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

Before reading and following the tutorial in NPM I installed the react-native-cli globally and it worked just fine

But in the tutorial it asks you to install `sinopia`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cli

Then it gives you these instructions

```
react-native$ npm set registry http://localhost:4873/
react-native$ npm adduser --registry http://localhost:4873/
# Check that it worked:
react-native$ npm config list
react-native$ npm unpublish --force
react-native$ npm publish
react-native$ cd react-native-cli/
react-native-cli$ npm unpublish --force
react-native-cli$ npm publish
```

But the `unpublish` part gave me an error. the same for the 'publish' aprt.

(By the way, publish what?!)

Then it says to uninstall react-native-cli

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

After that I couldn't reinstall react-native-cli.

It says the package is not available.

> npm ERR! 404 no such package available : react-native-cli
>
> npm ERR! 404
>
> npm ERR! 404  'react-native-cli' is not in the npm registry.

What is this?! How can I fix it?

**@edit**

By the way, I don't understand why, in the Get Started tutorial it doesn't tell us how to install the react-native-cli nor gives us a link. It just states:

> The React Native CLI #
>
> Node.js comes with npm, which lets you install the React Native command line interface.

**@edit2**

I just managed to install react-native-cli by removing the 'registry' entry from npm config, installing it and adding Sinopia again.

I thought Sinopia worked as a proxy. If it is not found in local repository, it looks for it in NPMJS...

I even tried to install other things and I could (`wdio`, `nodemon`), I just got an error with react-native-cli.

It seems that something is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you on Windows

I don't think you need sinopia.

Tutorials was little improved on master branch of the docs: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/getting-started.html

In short:

1. Install node.js
2. Install react-native-cli: `npm install react-native-cli`
3. Install & setup Android SDK
4. Create & run project

   - `react-native init AwesomeProject`
   - `cd AwesomeProject`
   - `react-native start`
   - `react-native run-android`